# Loop through binary data chunks from stdin in Bash

Tags: bash, pipe, binary

I'm looking for something like `while IFS= read -r -n $length str; do ... done` but for binary data.  Is it possible to do this using `dd` or other tools? Is there some technique to make these tools able to see when pipe -which stdin is actually read from it- is closed and terminate loop?

Currently I encode and decode binary data and use `read` but It's so slow.. (`base64 | while read -r -n77 str; do echo $str | base64 -d; ... done`)

Comment: `bash` doesn't support storing binary data in its variables. You'll need a shell that does like `zsh`, or better use a programming language like `perl`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I think bash can store raw data in its variables except for `NUL` byte.. Actually problem is detecting when pipe was closed. I can read that data with `dd` or any tool that is able to do magic with binary data. If I can use something like `select()` or `poll()` directly in Bash, I can use `dd` to solve problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bash` can't hold binary data in its variables. It's already bad enough to process *text* with shell loops,  it would be even worse for processing binary data. The shell is the tool to run other tools.

Also note that the `read` buit-in command reads characters, not bytes.

Also, `dd` does *one* `read` system call, so a `dd bs=77 count=1` won't necessarily read 77 bytes especially if stdin is a pipe (the GNU implementation of `dd` has `iflag=fullblock` for that).

Here, you want to use a data processing programming language like `perl`:

In `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=\77}
  print "Do something with the 77 byte long <$_> record\n"'
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -vRS='.{,77}' '{print "the record is in <" RT ">"}'
```

If you want to use a shell, your best option is probably `zsh` which is the only one that can store binary data in its variables:

```
while LC_ALL=C IFS= read -ru0 -k77 record; do
  print -r -- "you may only call builtins with $record
    anyway since you can't pass NUL bytes in arguments
    to an external command"
done
```

If all you want to do is pass each chunk as stdin to a new invocation of `some command`, then you can use GNU `split` and its `--filter` option:

```
split -b 77 --filter='some command'
```

`--filter` starts a new shell to evaluate `some command` for each chunk. Unless your `sh` does the optimisation already by itself, you can do:

```
split -b 77 --filter='exec some command'
```

To save a fork.

Using `dd`, you could parse its stderr output to find out the end of input. You'd need the GNU specific `iflag=fullblock` as well:

```
while
  {
    report=$({
      LC_ALL=C dd bs=77 iflag=fullblock count=1 2>&3 |
        some command >&4 3>&- 4>&-
    } 3>&1)
  } 4>&1
  [ "${report%%+*}" -eq 1 ]
do
  : nothing
done
```

If the input size is multiple of 77 though, `some command` will be run an extra time with an empty input.

Comment: Unfortunately I can just use some *coreutils* binaries and since this functionality is portion of bigger script it has hard dependency on Bash.

Comment: @xin, you can call `perl` from `bash`. `bash` is not part of `coreutils`. What about `gawk`?

Comment: Your second paragraph is incorrect. It is true the `read` built-in in bash reads characters, not bytes. But the `read` system call *does* read bytes. Thus `dd bs=77 count=1` will read 77 *bytes*, not 77 characters.

Comment: @Patrick, I was referring indeed to the `read` builtin, and then pointing out that `dd bs=77 count=1` only reads _up to_ 77 bytes, not necessarily 77 bytes (when the input is a pipe for instance, you may need more than one `read` system call to read 77 bytes if not as much is available in the pipe upon the first read) in two unrelated statements. Will clarify.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for updating. `split --filter` trick was very helpful, Although I should change my code since it expects a command.. Are you sure your `dd` solution works? I've fixed test error (`[ -eq]`) but it does just one iterate..

Comment: @StephaneChazelas `line 8: [: : integer expression expected`

Comment: @xin, we store the stderr of `dd` into that `$report`, so we can parse the `1+0 records in`... Possibly you got an error message as well. What happens when you run that dd command manually?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Your dd loop sometimes invokes `some command` for once, sometimes twice and sometimes more. Of course for same arguments and same input. By running `dd` manually I get `some command` called with first block in stdin.