# A shell-like environment for binary processing

Tags: files, scripting, binary

This question came to me a couple of times before, now in response to the question
[Loop through binary data chunks from stdin in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118752/loop-through-binary-data-chunks-from-stdin-in-bash)
Answers given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993434/what-language-is-to-binary-as-perl-is-to-text were also not satisfactory.

I'm looking for a scripting environment suited specifically to handle I/O with binary files. I know I can use one of the fully-fledged programming languages (c/Python/...) but they have an enormous initialization and coding overhead (allocation and fread/fwrite in c, bitstrings in Python...) not to mention they are less suited for scripting (calling other applications from it). Perl is no better with its `unpack` functions, string-oriented operation and goofy syntax.

Something like `od`, but as a language.

What I expect:

1. set or change endianness with a single switch/command.
2. simple specification of requested type (something like extending bash `read var` with `int32 var`,  `float var` etc.).
3. handling of binary through pipes, skipping of specified number of bytes.
4. standard scripting flow control (for/if/...) that we are used to.

I'd like to process raw data (photography, scientific data, unknown and poorly documented formats) with the same ease and insight that you get when inspecting ASCII files. I'm using `c` now, but it's not optimal for ad-hoc scripting, and can't be interactive.

Does anyone know a tool like that? No clicky GUI software, please, it needs to work over ssh, from other scripts and so on. "Does not exist" is an acceptable, but depressing answer.

Comment: It does not take away the pain of startup time, but I find the bytes from Python 3.3, together with [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) very workable: `chain = ls["-a"] | grep["-v", "\\.py"] | wc["-l"]; chain()` Have you looked at that?

Comment: You could take the C code you have now and turn it into a set of command-line tools you could use in a bash script.  While you can't put binary into a shell variable, you can stash it in named ('fifo') pipes; their contents are in held in memory until you want to read them.

Comment: There's a serious flaw in your reasoning WRT python and perl, BTW. While individual command line tools are compiled, shell scripts aren't and involve much forking (if you want expensive, forking is it). Your discussion, other question, etc, imply you would be fine w/ using bash here if it could handle binary. Python and perl scripts are *both* pre-compiled. If you benchmark a reasonably complex python or perl script vs. a parallel bash script, the perl or python will be *an order of magnitude faster*. If you don't believe me, you are welcome to search the web for evidence to the contrary.

Comment: I'm not looking for a tool that runs fast, I'm looking for something I can *code* fast. For instance, if I have a strange program that outputs a binary int for array size of structs (int,float,float) that follow after it, I'd like to quickly read the array size and loop over the array, possibly calculating some cumulative or maximum of some components, or just print one component as ascii column for gnuplot processing.
Anthon: thank you, I didn't know about this, it will be useful.
goldilocks: I'm trying to avoid that but I may just write my own tool at the end :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial on how to use `perl`'s `unpack` (ᵔᴥᵔ)

Comment: @orion All apologies, I misinterpreted "enormous initialization...overhead".  I've often thought it is unfortunate that languages operating on a higher level than C generally make working on raw bytes more awkward.  BTW, as an alternative to pack/unpack there is [vec()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html) -- although it sounds like you are someone who just does not get along w/ perl, lol.  Whatever language you end up using, the "coding overhead" will probably be mostly eliminated if you can abstract and develop a library of common functions for these purposes...

Comment: ...E.g., if you are literally have to type out `fread()` all the time, you're doing something wrong (it smacks loudly of spagetti -- a lack of *structure* and organization).  In any case good luck!

Comment: I guess it's too obvious I dislike perl. `unpack` is almost what I want, so I'll have to make peace with it. I was hoping there was an alternative out there. I need this for manual checking, prototyping and quick-and-dirty single-use code. When I need structure, I use `c` anyway.

Comment: You could write your own in Lisp http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-parsing-binary-files.html

Comment: im fairly sure `dc` meets your requirements and its probably already installed on your computer. Still, is it very difficult to just filter input with `od`? If you block it off correctly - and filter as necessary with `tr` and `sed` and similar - you can get a reasonable amount of performance for a prototype. `dc` though, is blazing fast. it just takes some getting used to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do have the exact same problem than you for years as well.

For simple non-interactive uses, I like to use the binary block editor [BBE](http://bbe-.sourceforge.net/bbe.html).
BBE is to binary as SED is to text, including its archaic syntax and simplicity, however, it has a lot of features missing from what I often need, so I have to combine it with other tools. So, BBE is only a partial solution.
Also note that BBE hasn't had any updates or improvements for years.

Of course one can use `xxd` before and `xxd -r` after editing the data with text-based tools, but that won't work when the data in question is large and random access is required, for example when processing block devices.

(Note: For Windows, there is at least the costly, proprietary WinHex scripting language, but that won't get us anywhere.)

For more complicated binary editing, I usually fall back to Python as well, even though it sometimes is too slow for large files, which is it's main drawback. I hope [Pyston](https://github.com/dropbox/pyston) (Python employing LLVM to compile to optimized machine code) will someday mature enough to be usable, or even better, someone will design and implement a free compact, fast and versatile binary processing scripting language, which AFAIK doesn't exist for U*IX like systems yet.

UPDATE

I also happen to use the homebrew, open source Intel x86 assembler [flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net), or fasm for short, that evolved into much more than just an assembler.

It has a powerful, textblock-based macro preprocessor (itself a turing complete language) with a syntax in the tradition of the borland turbo assembler macro language, but much more advanced.

Also, it has a data manipulation language, which allows to binary include arbitrary files, do all kinds of binary and arithmetic manipulation on it (integer only) at "compile time" and write the result into an output file. This data manipulation language has control strutures and is also turing complete.

It is much easier to use than writing a program that does some binary manipulation in C and probably even in python. Plus, it loads blindingly fast, as it is a small sized executable with almost no external dependecies (There are 2 versions: either it only requires libc or it can run as a static executable directly on the Linux kernel ABI).

It does have some ruff edges, like

1. not supporting concurrency
2. being writting in 32 bit x86 assembly (works on x86_64 though), you probably need qemu or a similar emulator if you want to run it on anything else than x86 or x86_64
3. it's powerful macro preprocessor language is turing complete, this means you better have some experience with languages like Lisp, Haskell, XSLT, or probably M4 would be the best choice.
4. all data that is to be written into the output file are performed in a "flat" buffer in memory, and this buffer can grow but not shrink until the output file has been written and fasm terminated. This means that one can only generate files at most as large as you have main memory left in a single run of fasm.
5. data can only be written into a single output file for each run of fasm
6. yeah, it is homebrew, a really neat and clever one though

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily have to "make peace" with Perl's unpack... one of the great things about perl is how you can abuse the parser and symbol table to make your own language, in a custom package.

Is this basically what you're looking for?

```
use MyBinLib;
my $struct= struct(
  pack => 8,
  size => 400,
  fields => [int32('foo','bar','baz'), float32('x1','x2','x3','x4'), int8, int8, int16('z')]
);
while (my $rec= $struct->read(<STDIN>)) {
  printf "x1 = %d, x2 = $d\n", $rec->x1, $rec->x2;
}
```

The exercise then is to learn enough perl to write the MyBinLib package.  Ask in a Perl forum and people would probably be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across `beav` it has macros but I couldn't find scripting,

`apt-cache show beav` extract :

> With beav, you can edit a file in HEX, ASCII, EBCDIC, OCTAL, DECIMAL,
>   and  BINARY. You can display but not edit data in FLOAT mode. You can
>   search or  search and replace in any of these modes. Data can be
>   displayed in BYTE,  WORD, or DOUBLE WORD formats. While displaying
>   WORDS or DOUBLE WORDS the  data can be displayed in INTEL's or
>   MOTOROLA's byte ordering. Data of any  length can be inserted at any
>   point in the file. The source of this data  can be the keyboard,
>   another buffer, or a file. Any data that is being  displayed can be
>   sent to a printer in the displayed format. Files that are  bigger than
>   memory can be handled.

Then there's `xxd` which converts to/from binary/ascii display mode and could be combined together with `sed` or `vi`, but hasn't got the byte swapping feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go for the gold and drop down into C or ASM.
If you are working with raw binary, just bounce it straight off the register.
You are 'already there'.